# Spellchecking w SolrNet 400 Bad Request using colon : in spellcheck query

Tags: solr, solrnet

I'm using SolrNet and when I pass a query that has a colon in it, I receive this error:

```
Apache Tomcat/6.0.32 - Error report
The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect (null).
```

The code sample looks like this:

```
var results = SolrOps.Query(request.Query, new QueryOptions
            {
                SpellCheck = new SolrNet.Commands.Parameters.SpellCheckingParameters
                {
                    Collate = true,
                    Build = true,
                    Query = "test:"

                }

            });
```

Am I required to strip the colon manually, or is there some option I can set (either in SOLR or SOLRNet) to fix this?

Comment: Why do you have a colon in your query?

Comment: It's a user generated query.  I'm spell checking their input to see if there's a good replacement.   FYI, this only seems to happen on SpellChecking, not on regular queries.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking that spellchecking does not support special characters and you will need to filter/strip those out of the query term(s) prior to submitting the request to Solr via SolrNet.